# How to show y-axis differences in highchart multi axis

Tags: highcharts

How to create a multi-axis highchart showing difference of multiple axis in different color. (how to show the orange color in attached image)

Expected graph.

[image]

Comment: Either use stacking, or use columnrange. The orange part needs to be it's own series in both cases.

Comment: @ewolden, I will try in that way, Could pls add fiddler example if possible..

Comment: Look at this chart: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5opfhq9g/
Let me know if you need any explanation

Comment: Thanks, this is what i need, works perfectly, Is there any way we could get that red cross symbol...

Comment: @ewolden, Thank you so much, i was able to get that cross like below https://jsfiddle.net/sathishkumar_v/zymwgqkv/6/

add your answer, i will accept and upvote

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use column chart with 2 series (orange and grey) and plotOptions.grouping property set to false. I added 2 additional line series with disabled mouseTracking, and markers similar to markers on your image. Additionally i formatted tooltip to display the orange over value.

Cross marker SVG:

`Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross = function(x, y, w, h) {
  return ['M', x, y, 'L', x + w, y + h, 'M', x + w, y, 'L', x, y + h, 'z'];
};`

plotOptions.grouping:

`plotOptions: {
    column: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      grouping: false
    }
  },`

And our series:

```
var orangeData = [1, 3, 8, 13, 11, 13, 15, 25, 29, 31, 27, 25, 16, 11, 10, 4, 4, 8, 2, 1, 1],
  greyData = [3, 4, 11, 11, 12, 14, 15, 21, 25, 25, 23, 21, 15, 13, 12, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1];

series: [{
    data: orangeData,
    color: '#f7931e',
    tooltip: {
      pointFormatter: function() {
        return 'Orange value is higher than grey value by: ' + (orangeData[this.index] - greyData[this.index])
      }
    }
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    data: orangeData,
    color: '#ec1c24',
    marker: {
      symbol: 'cross',
      lineColor: null,
      lineWidth: 2
    },
    enableMouseTracking: false
  }, {
    data: greyData,
    color: '#989898'
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    data: greyData,
    color: '#231f20',
    enableMouseTracking: false
  }]
```

You can take a look at jsFiddle demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xpwdhrvz/